# If the intersection of probabilities $A$ and $B$ is $0$, what does it say about $A$, $B$, and their union?

Tags: probability

What does it mean for $P(A)$, $P(B)$, and their union if the probability of their intersection is $0$?

I thought that since the intersection is $0$, $A$ and $B$ would be disjoint events meaning that the union would also be $0$, so we wouldn't be able to say anything about $P(A)$ or $P(B)$. However, it feels like I am missing something.

Comment: union of disjoint events is not zero

Comment: Consider this : Out of 7 Days in a week , there is heavy traffic on Mon-Fri : P(T)=5/7. Movie theatre is full on Sat : P(M) = 1/7. What is the Probability that traffic is heavy AND Movie theatre is full P(T AND M) ? What is the Probability that heavy traffic OR Movie theatre is full P(T OR M) ?

Comment: Let $A$ denote the event that a coin flip comes up Heads.  Let $B$ denote the event that the coin flip instead comes up Tails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the probability of the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is zero, it is something like the case where $A$ is heads and $B$ is tails, in other words both outcomes are not possible at the same time. The word for this is not "disjoint" but "mutually exclusive". The union is not zero, it's just the sum of the two.
$$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)
$$
For example the probability of "heads" or "tails" when throwing a coin is $\frac12+\frac12=1$.

Usually the union is not the sum, but
$$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).
$$
The intersection is subtracted because we count $P(A\cap B)$ twice when we add $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.